# Como obter o TimeStamp em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, timestamp

Gostaria de sabe como faço em `JavaScript` para obter o `Timestamp`? Um número que representa a data e hora atual. Sei que conseguimos o objeto para data e hora através de:

```
var d = new Date();
```

Mas não sei como prosseguir a partir dai.

Comment: O que seria esse `Timestamp`? Lembre-se que sistemas diferentes possuem maneiras diferentes de representar uma data por um número. Um dos mas conhecidos é o "Unix time" (com 32 ou 64 bits), mas existem outros (Python por exemplo utiliza um `float` em vez de um inteiro). Verifique se o formato usado pelo JavaScript é o mesmo que você precisa para sua aplicação. E, se aplicável, não se esqueça de prestar atenção no fuso horário.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Você pode usar o `getTime()` do objeto [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```
// Pegar do horário atual
var timestamp = new Date().getTime();

// Pegar de uma data específica
var timestamp = new Date(2013, 11, 17).getTime();
```

Mas atenção porque essa data/hora é fornecida pelo sistema operacional do cliente, se você precisar de alguma segurança ou a informação for para a base, use algum método na sua aplicação no servidor(back-end).

**UPDATE:**

Um detalhe importante que passou despercebido por mim - e parece que por todos - é que o parâmetro *month* do construtor do objeto `Date` é indexado por zero(zero-indexed), ou seja, começa a contar a partir do zero, então: 0 = Janeiro e 11 = Dezembro. No exemplo acima, usei o número `12` para extrair a data de hoje(17/12/13) porém como Dezembro é 11, o resultado do exemplo é `Fri Jan 17 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (Horário brasileiro de verão)`, ou seja, **Janeiro**, pois ele joga a data pra frente - ou para trás - fazendo o cálculo. Mas isso é uma outra história.

Comment: +1 pela observação sobre o mês. Isso sempre acontece em Javascript e também em Java. Porém eu sugiro editar a questão e não deixar o 12 em cima, pois um leitor apressado pode copiar o código e não ler a atualização.

Comment: @utluiz boa idéia, alterei o código.

Comment: @utluiz as respostas que não citam essa observação merecem upvote já que podem reproduzir um resultado errado?

Comment: @durtto No vejo problema. Ter uma informação a mais é bom, mas não totalmente necessário, a menos que é claro, que isto faça a resposta errada ou leve o leitor ao erro.

Comment: utluiz eu particularmente faria o que você disse acima. rs rs

Answer (score 7):

Como todos disseram:

```
new Date().getTime()
```

Ou então ainda mais simples:

```
Date.now()
```

Answer (score 5):

Só para constar uma outra maneira, além dos mencionados:

`+new Date`

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar

```js
new Date().getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

Com javascript puro é possivel pegar o timestamp assim:

```
console.log(new Date().getTime());
//ou
alert(new Date().getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

**Curto e grosso:**

```
+ new Date()
```

Um operador `+` dispara o método `valueOf` no objeto `Date` e retorna o *timestamp* (sem qualquer alteração).

**Detalhes:**

Em quase todos os navegadores atuais, você pode usar [`Date.now()`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.4) para obter o UTC *timestamp* em **milissegundos**; uma exceção notável é o IE8 e anterior ([veja tabela de compatibilidade](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Date.now)).

Para obter o *timestamp* em **segundos**, você pode usar:

```
Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
```

Ou, alternativamente, você poderia usar:

```
Date.now() / 1000 | 0
```

Que deve ser ligeiramente mais rápido, mas também menos legível ([veja também esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487977/using-bitwise-or-0-to-floor-a-number)).

Eu recomendaria usar `Date.now ()` (com correção de compatibilidade). É um pouco melhor porque é mais curto e não cria um novo objeto `Date`. No entanto, se você não quiser uma correção && compatibilidade máxima, poderá usar o método "antigo" para obter o registro de *timestamp* em **milissegundos**:

```
new Date().getTime()
```

Que você pode então converter para segundos como este:

```
Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000)
```

E você também pode usar o método `valueOf` que mostramos em baixo:

```
new Date().valueOf()
```

**Timestamp em milissegundos**

```js
var timeStampInMs = window.performance && window.performance.now && window.performance.timing && window.performance.timing.navigationStart ? window.performance.now() + window.performance.timing.navigationStart : Date.now();

console.log(timeStampInMs, Date.now());
```

Answer (score -3):

Em um exercício de um curso eu preciso colocar o relógio na tela, a solução que deu certo para mim foi a seguinte:

HTML

```
<body onload = carregar()> //na TAG <body> coloquei a função que será chamada no JS
.
     <p> A hora será exibida aqui... </p>
.
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
function carregar() { /*no script chamei a função declarada na TAG <body>*/
    var data = new Date;  /*objeto Date foi instanciado na variável data*/
    var h = data.getHours();  /*variável h recebe valor de parâmetro para pegar 
                               as horas*/
    var m = data.getMinutes(); /*variável m recebe valor de parâmetro para pegar 
                               os minutos*/
    var s = data.getSeconds(); /*variável s recebe valor de parâmetro para pegar 
                               os segundos*/
    var hora_atual = h+ ':' +m+ ':' +s; /*variável hora_atual recebe os valores 
                                        concatenados das variáveis h m s */
    p.innerHTML = `Hora atual: ${hora_atual}`; /* elemento HTML <p> é 
                                                modificado*/ 
    setInterval('carregar()', 1000); /*comando para chamar a função dentro de um 
                                       intervalo de tempo, 1000 é igual a 1 
                                       segundo */
    }
```